# How is this Uncaught TypeError: occurring?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I recently saved my questionnaire as a PHP file to include a validation script and am coming up with the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onClick' of null

It's also pointing me to line 163 of my javascript file which is the function for the "next" button on the first page.

The most common reason I've seen so far in everything I've been reading is that it's triggering before the element loads in the page.  In response to this I linked the .js file in the bottom of the body tag but it still gives me the same error.

The buttons on the HTML file I saved as a PHP still works fine with no problems.  Here's how I have everything coded.

```
//the function for the page change buttons//

    window.onload=function(){

//a bunch of variables come prior to this//
    var start = document.getElementById("start_btn");

    var p1a = document.getElementById("p1_next");

    var p2a = document.getElementById("p2_back");
    var p2b = document.getElementById("p2_next");
//more variables continued//

    start.onclick=function(){  //coded exactly the same as where the error occurs//
        welc_p.style.display="none";
        page01.style.display="block";
        window.location="#page01";
    };

    p1a.onclick=function(){         //line 163 where the error occurs//
        page01.style.display="none";
        page02.style.display="block";
        window.location="#page02";
    };

    p2a.onclick=function(){
        page01.style.display="block";
        page02.style.display="none";
        window.location="#page01";
    };

    p2b.onclick=function(){
        page02.style.display="none";
        page03.style.display="block";
        window.location="#page03";
    };
//more functions continued//

  }
```

The HTML I'm using as the button

```
    <div class="button" id="p1_next" style="width:22%; height:40px; margin:auto;">
        <div class="sub_title02">Next</div>
    </div>
```

I added a little extra just so you guys can see the flow of things and what's around the part that's giving an error.  I also went back and forth adding and "onclick" function to the buttons but that still didn't work.  Does anybody have any clue what's going wrong here?

Comment: Isn't the `<div class="button" id="p1_next" ...></div>` element created dynamically?

Comment: no I have it coded in there manually.

Comment: There is no html element with the id ```start_btn``` thus variable ```start``` is null and you cannot add an event handler to null.

Comment: no it's in my html for the welcome page, I only included the elements related to the problem here to avoid making a huge block of unnecessary coding to dig through.

Comment: ok why is this voted down? What's wrong with the question and the info I provided?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle where you show the complete html and javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The short and easy answer is, your selector doesn't find the specified element. Can you show the code including your html?

Either you misspelled the ID of the element you are trying to add the click event to, or as you proposed yourself the html is not loaded yet when you are executing your javascript.

Comment: the html code is at the very bottom of the example, do you need to see more than that?  The rest is a bunch of input fields so I just tried to show the important parts revolving around the error.

Comment: also I linked the javascript in at the bottom of  the body instead of up in the head section to make it load last.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I stumbled upon what was causing the problem.  From looking at the coding over and over so much I realized I forgot to give the textarea input a name like all the other inputs so I gave it one and continued scanning the code, eventually I uploaded it and noticed the problem was gone.  Just to be sure on what it was I deleted the name and tested it and the problem came back.

so I guess if a textarea in a PHP file doesn't have a name attribute it for some reason makes itself a self closing tag that gets ignored by the browser until it runs into the closing tag of another textarea WITH a name attribute.  So that's what caused the javascript to throw back the null error because the trigger element didn't exist because it was eaten by the textarea.... so there was nothing there when the javascript looked for it.  Thanks for taking the time to help me figure it out. :)